# Is UML suitable for designing a warehouse workflow?

Tags: uml, workflows, modeling

I need to design a warehouse workflow: the cartons that enter, then the flow of a box, returns, porcessing of damaged good, cancellation at different stages, and transfer from a stock to another. Each operation can also change the product.

What kind of UML diagram should I use for representing this kind of workflow? Component or activity diagram?  Or is there something more suitable?

Comment: I have the feeling I need a state machine diagram

Comment: state machines make sense for the different objets and worklflows on requests/orders/inbound and outbound deliveries. But states and transitions are not sufficient to give the full perspective on the full workflow logic, eventual cycles or parallel activities, not to speak of actors and subsystems/components involved. Moreover storage units can be more complex (e.g pallets, cartons, boxes, pieces and other possible aggregation forms (e.g. storage bins etc). You may therefore need more than one diagram depending on what you want to focus on

Comment: Please revise your question after reading [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question) and [Why is research important?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Thanks.

Comment: I slightly edited your question, to remove the narrative on your usual UML questions (which does not seem to add relevant information to the question).  Since you have considered a couple of diagrams, and in the comments you also wonder about SM diagrams,  it would be interesting to mention those that you envisaged and why you were hesitating.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to look for modelling a business process:

> The cartons that enter, then the flow of a box. Return, damaged good, cancellation at different stages, transfer from a stock to another. Each operation can also change the product.

If you're interested in the business analysis and optimizing business processes in close collaboration with business users, you could consider [BPMN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation) modelling.  It's a modelling language designed for exactly this purpose. it's also an ISO standard, as UML. And a couple of workflow engines support it.

But you can also go for UML.  THe most suitable diagram for process flows is the [**activity diagram**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram). Studies have proven that expressivity of UML activity diagrams are comparable to BPMN diagrams. It may be a little harder for buisness people to read (especially the gates), but has the advantage to facilitate the transition to a model for system implementation.